# How to keep UV after remesh

Tags: modeling

How do I keep the my UV after remesh I searched around and can't seem to find a good answer to my question any help will be appreciated hopefully someone has  a solution for me

Answer (score 10):

#### Option 1 (Transfer UVs)

Use the [Data Transfer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) modifier, and select "UVs" under "Face Corner Data". Make sure you click "Generate Data Layers" so it has somewhere to put the transferred coordinates, and play around with the mapping type to find the best result.

Pro:

- Allows re-using the same texture map(s).

Con:

- Cannot automatically handle seams.

#### Option 2 (New UVs, Transfer Texture)

Unwrap the re-meshed model separately, and use [Render Baking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html) in Cycles, for "Diffuse" colour and with "Selected to Active", to transfer your original model's textures to the remeshed geometry's new UVs.

Pro:

- Allows precision down to pixel scale.

Con:

- Requires texture duplication, inefficient and lossy.

Comment: for option 2 here's a tutorial : https://styly.cc/tips/retopology_bake/

Comment: Could you elaborate on option 1? Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201966/

Comment: sorry had to downvote due to the low quality option 1 explanation. if you can elaborate more i will reconsider upvoting.