# How to Remap UV to Remeshed Object?

Tags: modifiers, uv, remesh

I have downloaded this free 3D scanned model and was experimenting on the [Quad Remesher](https://exoside.com/quadremesher/) addon. After very good remeshing algorithm finished, I unfortunately lose the texture/material because it deletes the UV Map. So I tried to use the [`Transfer Data Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) to try to remap the UV Map, but so far I have not found any good sources that explain exactly how to do this except for this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOPAICgpoZU) and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_B1xZK-o-8) (they also claimed there was not enough documentation on the Data Transfer modifier) which I tried to follow with no success. I also found [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190494/how-to-keep-uv-after-remesh) but the answer about using the Data Transfer Modifier was of low quality. What am I doing wrong? What settings are incorrect in the below screenshot?

[image]

Applying the modifier in Blender 3.6 also didn't work despite both having the same point of origin and both aligned together.

[image]

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19oySc9OKjBCHSXfNDhbNls9FqEnCq8iS/view?usp=sharing) (170MB sorry I couldn't find a way to reduce it)

**UPDATE**: Thank you it works now! Unfortunately I found out that using the Transfer Data Modifier is definitely not the way to go, and adding a Subdivions Surface Modifier before the Transfer Data modifier made things even worst. Probably I will have to use another approach.

[image]

Comment: would that be ok for you as result? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHDGm.jpg

Comment: Hi chris! I guess so? at least something that works somewhat so I will understand how this Data Transfer Modifier usage process works and I will know that this process is not perfect :)

Comment: all you have to do is give them the same origin point ;) then apply modifier

Comment: FWIW here's an exploration using geometry nodes https://blenderartists.org/t/gorgious-photogrammetry-shenanigans/1454287?u=gorgious

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie: you have to give the same material and select both, when pressing generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, i did some more things i didn't wrote in comments.

1. put both on same location (as he said in his own video: yt tutorials suck :D )
2. give the remeshed body the same material
3. select both models, remeshed at last
4. press generate layers, apply modifier, result:

[image]

it worked on my computer in 3.5alpha and 4.0 so...it should work on 3.6

Comment: +1. Thanks for sharing! Now I know how to use it and I guess the Transfer Data Modifier is definitely not the way to go since it cannot cleanly transfer the data XD Do you have any idea what the best method is that yields better results than the Transfer Data Modifer?

Comment: no, i am sorry, i am really bad in UV editing -  still learning myself :( but i think with "primitive" methods it cannot be better because of different faces...

Comment: yeah you're right it's probably the way the faces were, that they aligned with the triangles better than the remeshed quads.